# MQTT.js with SSL could not connect

Tags: mqtt, mosca

I have correctly configured my Mosca Broker with an SSL certificate. I have verified that the server is running as the nmap command returns

```
8443 / tcp open https-alt
```

When I use the MQTT.js library with the following code, the browser returns the following error. Firefox can not establish a connection to the server in wss: //192.168.1.173: 8443 /.

I also do not receive the error in the connection. I do not know how to debug the error.

```
var client;

function loaded() {
  var options = {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
  client  = mqtt.connect('wss://192.168.1.173:8443', options)

  client.on('connect', function () {
    client.subscribe('presence')
  })

  client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
    // message is Buffer
    console.log(message.toString())
    document.getElementById('lista').innerHTML = document.getElementById('lista').innerHTML + '<li>'+message.toString()+'</li>'
  })

  client.on('error', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
  })
}
```

Comment: Have you imported the CA cert for the broker into firefox? If firefox does not trust the service it will not connect

Comment: Yes I have imported de CA cert but can't connect

Comment: And the CN for the server certificate matches the ip address?

Comment: Can you share the server code/command you are using to expose the broker on WSS?

Comment: Excuse me, my certificate was not correctly generated